# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' when performing Sum Distinct in Django 2.2.5. Was working on Django 2.1.7

Tags: django

My application uses this rather simple model, to access data from an existing table:

```
class Table01(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sucursal = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    remito = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    codcli = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    razon = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    domi = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    turno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    codart = models.TextField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    canti = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    tot = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "TABLE01"
        app_label = "datatables"
```

The backend for this database is SQLite

With Django 2.1.7 and this model, my application was performing successfully the following 
query:

```
sumrem = (Table01.objects.filter(fecha = some_date, turno = some_turno, codcli =some_customer).values("fecha", "turno", "sucursal", "remito", "razon")
.annotate(Sum(F("tot"), distinct=True)))
```

to get the distinct sum of the 'tot' field, which was working as expected on Django 2.1.7

When I upgraded to Django 2.2.5, this error appeared:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from .models import Table01
>>> from django.db.models import F, Sum, Count
>>> sumrem = Table01.objects.filter(fecha='2019-05-10', turno=4, codcli=50).values("fecha", "turno", "sucursal", "remito", "razon").annotate(Sum(F("tot"), distinct=True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ricardo/desarrollo/estacion/vr1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 26, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s does not allow distinct." % self.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Sum does not allow distinct.
```

I did a little research, and found that from version 2.2, according to the [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#models), "...The handling of `DISTINCT` aggregation is added to the `Aggregate` class. Adding `allow_distinct=True` as a class attribute on `Aggregate` subclasses allows a `distinct` keyword argument to be specified on initialization to ensure that the aggregate function is only called for each distinct value of expression"

So, I created this little piece of code, following the example on the reference of [Aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#creating-your-own-aggregate-functions) to implement the `Sum` function, and set the `allow_distinct` class attribute, to be able to pass `distinct=True` in the query.

```
#models.py
from django.db.models import Aggregate

class SumD(Aggregate):
    function = "SUM"
    allow_distinct = True


class CountD(Aggregate):
    function = "COUNT"
    allow_distinct = True
```

When I run the query now, this error happens:

```
>>> from .models import Table01, SumD, CountD
>>> from django.db.models import F, Sum, Count
>>> sumrem = Table01.objects.filter(fecha='2019-05-10', turno=4, codcli=50).values("fecha", "turno", "sucursal", "remito", "razon").annotate(SumD(F("tot"), distinct=True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ricardo/desarrollo/estacion/vr1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1032, in annotate
    if arg.default_alias in kwargs:
  File "/home/ricardo/desarrollo/estacion/vr1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 64, in default_alias
    return '%s__%s' % (expressions[0].name, self.name.lower())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

And now is when I'm really lost :) any help is really appreciated.

Sincerely, Ricardo.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Apparently, the `Aggregate()` class needs a name assigned to the result, unlike the 2.1 version where you didn't need the name, and the default name would be

```
field__sum
```

This code works:

```
sumrem = Table01.objects
.values('fecha', 'turno', 'sucursal', 'remito', 'razon')
.filter(fecha=some_date, turno=some_turno, codcli=some_customer)
.annotate(tot=SumD(F('tot'), distinct=True))
```

I believe this should be documented better. Best regards. Ricardo.